# How to solve with MATLAB Microwave Engineering David Pozar problem 29 chapter 2 Transmission Lines Theory

Tags: matlab

**How to solve with MATLAB Problem 29 
of chapter 2 Transmission Lines Theory
from Microwave Engineering, D.Pozar**

The problem headline:

[image]

the literature source is available here:

[https://www.amazon.co.uk/Microwave-Engineering-Written-Publisher-Hardcover/dp/B00SLRKBV2/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1529281040&sr=8-1&keywords=David+Pozar+Microwave+Engineering](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Microwave-Engineering-Written-Publisher-Hardcover/dp/B00SLRKBV2/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1529281040&sr=8-1&keywords=David%20Pozar%20Microwave%20Engineering)

one can read excerpts of the book here:
http://www2.electron.frba.utn.edu.ar/~jcecconi/Bibliografia/Ocultos/Libros/Microwave_Engineering_David_M_Pozar_4ed_Wiley_2012.pdf

There's also a telegraphic solutions manual with some errors and no trace of MATLAB available here:

https://www.scribd.com/doc/176505749/Microwave-engineering-pozar-4th-Ed-solutions-manual

Comment: When asking for answers to worksheet problems, even if you answer themselves, you need to ask them in a *precise* way with a specific question, not just "how to solve". Also, this isn't even a signal processing, but a transmission line theory question, which doesn't even fit here.

Comment: Hi Marcus, this is just an academic exercise. Pozar's Microwave Engineering poses concise questions, as above shown, the question couldn't be more precise because it's THE problem 2.29 of that book. The 'How to solve with MATLAB ..' is because there may be different approaches: some people my simply define some variables and solve for the key answers, or perhaps you want to use tools like the Smith chart to solve the same problem.

Comment: Pozar's solution manual for some exercises points directly to advanced simulation programs, some of them really expensive in comparison with a MATLAB student license.

Comment: It's curious why you say that 'this isn't even a signal processing ..'. I am sure you are aware that the words 'Circuit' 'Filter' 'Network' and 'Signals' are synonyms. One can say that the X(f) is an input signal to the filter  Y(f), or one could say, from the signal processing point of view, that X(f) is the filter and H(f) is the signal. Transmission Lines is just a chapter, but clearly It Is Signal Processing, the S parameters are signal processing and the bilinear transform to obtain the Smith Chart is, a mathematical transform, so see network impedances, don't you agree?

Comment: Transmission lines lossless, lossy, .. is equivalent the 2 wire model for a wide range of devices to process signals, like filtering, phase delay, modulation, demodulation, split, sum, subtract, amplify, attenuate ..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because transmission line theory is not signal processing.

Comment: John, the way to have that discussion is to post a question in Meta and refer to this question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the following broken-down MATLAB script generates the spiral that the impedance follows along the lossy transmission line detailed in the problem 29 chapter 2 **Transmission Lines Theory** in page 93 of **Microwave Engineering** 4th edition literature reference.

Since there's no way to attach the compact MATLAB script to this answer, I am sending the compact MATLAB script **pozar_02_exercise_29.m** by email to anyone who emails me asking for copy, along with the following support functions to plot the Smith chart: **Smith_plotGammaCircle.m Smith_plotRefLine2PhaseCircle.m** .

I can also send the script in new format Livescript, that shows both code and results in 2 separate aligned columns.

In this ansser the code is firstly broken down and explained, afterwards the results column is shown.

[image]

```
Z0=50           % ohm
Zgen=50
Vgen=10       % Volt
ZL=100

syms lambda 
alpha_dB=.5/lambda  % [dB/lambda]
Np2dB=10*log10(exp(1)^2)
alpha_Np=alpha_dB/Np2dB

beta=2*pi/lambda  % [m^-1]
L=2.3*lambda        % length of transmission line [m]

gamma=alpha_Np+1j*beta
gamma_L=gamma*L
gamma_L_rad=double(gamma_L)  % =   0.1323 +14.4513i
```

sometimes for the complex propagation constant gamma, units Np/m and degree are mixed like it happens in the solutions manual for this exercise.

The solutions manual shows

```
% gamma=.1325 +1j*108º.
```

108 degree is the remainder of imag(gamma_degree)/360, in degree, should be in radians:

```
14.4513*180/pi-floor(14.4513*180/pi/360)*360
```

reflection coefficients on both sides of the transmission line

```
refl_Load=(ZL-Z0)/(ZL+Z0)
refl_gen=refl_Load*exp(-2*gamma_L_rad)
```

TL input impedance (from generator)

```
Zin=Z0*(ZL+Z0*tanh(gamma_L_rad))/(Z0+ZL*tanh(gamma_L_rad)
```

TL input power

```
Pin=(abs(Vgen*Zin/(Zgen+Zin)))^2/(2*Z0*(1-(abs(refl_gen))^2)*exp(2*real(gamma_L_rad))
```

PLoad power reaching load

```
PLoad=(abs(Vgen*Zin/(Zgen+Zin)))^2/(2*Z0)*(1-(abs(refl_Load))^2)
```

lost power

```
Ploss=Pin-PLoad
```

perhaps of use too, the maximum available power from generator:

```
Pmax_gen=.5*(abs(Vgen))^2/(4*real(Zgen))
```

Alternatively, just considering power decay:

alpha_dB and alpha_Np are per metre.

```
alpha=double(alpha_Np*L)

Pout=Pin*exp(-2*alpha)
```

Error in the solutions manual: it assumes
that both generator and load both matched; generator to TL and TL to load. And then calculates V0plus

```
absV0plus_all_match=abs(Vgen/2*exp(-real(gamma_L_rad)))
```

Instead, one has to use the following:

[image]

It's reasonable to consider that V0plus =Vgen*Zin/(Zgen+Zin)*(exp(g_L)+refl_gen*exp(-gamma_L_rad)) should be used, 2.89a in [POZAR] pg81

```
Vin=Vgen*Zin/(Zin+Zgen)*1/(exp(gamma_L_rad)+refl_gen*exp(-gamma_L_rad))
absVin=abs(Vin)
```

would be the correct start voltage for the procedure followed in the solutions manual.

But because expressions 2.92/93/94 are readily available, the answers have already been provided.

This Pin is the same as the above used

```
Pin=(abs(Vgen*Zin/(Zgen+Zin)))^2/(2*Z0*(1-(abs(refl_gen))^2)*exp(2*real(gamma_L_rad))
```

And it's not the other apparently correct

```
Vgen*Zin/(Zin+Zgen)   
abs(Vgen*Zin/(Zin+Zgen))   

Loss_dB=double(alpha_dB*L)
10*log10(Pin)-10*log10(PLoad)   

10*log10(exp(2*alpha))
```

0.21 dB missing, the perturbation method is not exact

Generator and TL are matched, but TL and load are not. And it's not the other apparently correct

```
Vgen*Zin/(Zin+Zgen)

abs(Vgen*Zin/(Zin+Zgen))
```

Comment: Zin with lossless TL would be

```
Zin_lossless=Z0*(ZL+1j*Z0*tan(imag(gamma_L_rad)))/(Z0+1j*ZL*tan(imag(gamma_L_rad)))
```

same as

```
Zin_lossless=Z0*(ZL+1j*Z0*tan(2*pi*2.3))/(Z0+1j*ZL*tan(2*pi*2.3))
```

All the results returned by the above lines are as follows:

```
alpha_dB =1/(2*lambda)
Np2dB =   8.685889638065037
alpha_Np =281474976710656/(4889721167171369*lambda)

gamma_L_rad =  0.132398642847158 +14.451326206513048i

refl_Load =   0.333333333333333
refl_gen = -0.206936161907528 + 0.150347922208021i


Zin = 31.588363022059227 +10.163454575205781i


Pin =   0.198382847405214

PLoad =   0.144789944222718


Ploss =   0.053592903182496


Pmax_gen = 0.25


alpha =   0.132398642847158

Pout =  0.152231357248704


absV0plus_all_match =   4.379958588165586


Vin =  0.155584072758048 - 3.279133570422918i

absVin = 3.282822471040817


Zin_lossless =
 26.928588541323329 +11.871170407231373i
```

And now with Smith Chart

```
Z0=50; ZL=100;

sm1=smithchart; ax=gca; hold all; 
refl_ZL=(ZL-Z0)/(ZL+Z0); 

plot(ax,real(refl_ZL),imag(refl_ZL),...
                                              'o','Color',[1 0 0],...
                                              'LineWidth',2,...
                                              'MarkerEdgeColor','b',...
                                              'MarkerFaceColor',[.8 .2 .2],...
                                              'MarkerSize',7)                                   % ZL 


 plot(ax,refl_mod(end).*cos(a(end)),refl_mod(end).*sin(a(end)),...
                                               'o','Color',[1 0 0],...
                                               'LineWidth',2,...
                                               'MarkerEdgeColor','b',...
                                               'MarkerFaceColor',[.2 .8 .2],...
                                               'MarkerSize',7)        % Zin at generator 

[x_swr,y_swr]=Smith_plotGammaCircle(ax,ZL,Z0,[1 .4 .4])

refl_in=…
refl_mod(end).*cos(a(end))+1j*refl_mod(end).*sin(a(end))
Zin_gen=Z0*(1+refl_in)/(1-refl_in)

[x_swr,y_swr]=Smith_plotGammaCircle(ax,Zin_gen,Z0,[.4 1 .4])

SWR_Load=(1+abs(refl_ZL))/(1-abs(refl_ZL))
SWR_gen=(1+abs(refl_in))/(1-abs(refl_in))

str_swr_load=['SWR Load = ' num2str(SWR_Load)]
str_swr_gen=['SWR Generator = ' num2str(SWR_gen)]

legend(ax,'ZL','Zgen',str_swr_load,str_swr_gen)
```

[image]

Zoom in

```
Smith_plotRefLine2PhaseCircle(ax,ZL,Z0,[.6 1 .6])
Smith_plotRefLine2PhaseCircle(ax,Zin_gen,Z0,[.6 1 .6])

syms lambda
alpha_dB=.5/lambda  % [dB/lambda]
Np2dB=10*log10(exp(1)^2);alpha_Np=alpha_dB/Np2dB
beta=2*pi/lambda;L=2.3*lambda

g=alpha_Np+1j*beta    % g=gamma=alpha+1j*beta
g_L=g*L;g_L=double(simplify(g_L))
```

angle to run along TL: beta*L=pi rad means 360º around Smith Chart
so to match the imag(g_L) angle with Smith chart angle, double it.

```
N1=100
da=2*pi/N1  % angle differential for 2*pi around Smith Chart = lambda/2 

amount_full_turns=floor(14.4513*180/pi/360)
```

angle rads left when no full turns left

```
14.4513-floor(14.4513*180/pi/360)

amount_da_rem=floor((14.4513-floor(14.4513*180/pi/360))/da)
```

total amount angle steps needed to achieve N1 resolution

```
N2=N1*amount_full_turns+amount_da_rem
a0=angle(refl_ZL)
a=double(linspace(a0,2*imag(g_L),N2));

refl_mod=linspace(refl_ZL,refl_ZL*exp(-real(g_L)),N2)
plot(ax,refl_mod.*cos(a),refl_mod.*sin(a),…
                                                    '-','LineWidth',.5,'Color',[1 0 0]) 
plot(ax,refl_mod(end).*cos(a(end)),refl_mod(end).*sin(a(end)),…
                                                                        'o','Color',[0 1 0],...
                                                                        'LineWidth',2,...
                                                                        'MarkerEdgeColor','b',...
                                                        'MarkerFaceColor',[.8 .2 .2],...
                                                                        'MarkerSize',7) % ZL 
 axis([-0.4008   0.3832  -0.4103  0.3737])
```

[image]

Additional comment:

the following expressions are for lossless transmission line

[image]

```
Vgen*Zin/(Zin+Zgen)*1/(exp(1j*imag(gamma_L_rad))+refl_Load*exp(-1j*imag(gamma_L_rad)))
abs(Vgen*Zin/(Zin+Zgen)*1/(exp(1j*imag(gamma_L_rad))+refl_Load*exp(-1j*imag(gamma_L_rad))))

Vgen*Z0/(Z0+Zgen)*exp(-1j*imag(gamma_L_rad))/(1-refl_Load*refl_gen*exp(-1j*2*imag(gamma_L_rad)))
abs(Vgen*Z0/(Z0+Zgen)*exp(-1j*imag(gamma_L_rad))/(1-refl_Load*refl_gen*exp(-1j*2*imag(gamma_L_rad))))
```

cannot be applied to lossy transmission lines  because different input voltages are obtained:

```
%%%%%%% end of answer
```

Comment: This has popped up in my review queue a couple of times. Having scanned through the answer, I must say, it seems dense and informative. One thing I would like to suggest however is to remove your contact information from the answer. I think I may have noticed one more answer where you have left your contact information in. I think that it would be best if the contact information stayed in your profile as it happens with all other members of the board. Have you considered setting up your [developer story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/join) through SO?

Comment: Hi Peter, if for instance some one wants to contact you by email, what would be the steps? 1. click on the link in your name next to your photo 2. then once in your profile scroll down and click on contact,  then 3.- either fill out the form, or if one wants to copy your email address to their contacts list, copy and past your email address? isn't it easier just a single click on the link to the email address supplied in the same answer?

Comment: regarding the developer story, thanks for the advice but I don't think I am going to use it, just starting, rather ask questions and supply answers, should be ok.

Comment: Hi John, we've noticed that you edited/rolled back some of your posts to include your contact info again. Please, refrain from doing so. SE is supposed to be a Q&A site where the questions and their answers are clean from any noise. You can, of course, add your contact info freely on your profile. For more information, please read [Are taglines & signatures disallowed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5038).